# JNA - getting all visible window handles on OSX

Tags: java, macos, jna, window-handles

I am looking for a way to get(in z order), move and resize visible windows on OSX using Java and JNA. Goal of the project is to manage 3rd party windows, so I do not own the windows and cannot access them via simple java code. I already do this on windows7/8, which is an easy task with the user32.dll. I already wasted hours googling but I cannot find any documentation or anything about how to accomplish this on the latest OSX. So my question is - what is the OSX equivalence to the User32.dll with stuff like FindWindow, EnumWindows, SetWindowPos etc?

Or any other advice on how to accomplish something like this.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using old Carbon functions. [PDF Reference](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Window_Manager/Window_Manager.pdf). Looks like `GetWindowList` and `GetNextWindow` is what you need.

You can find a sample mapping for Carbon functions [here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/mac/Carbon.java)

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. I will study this and come back with the results.

Comment: It seems like Carbon will be dropped out from OSX very soon. Are there any newer alternatives?

Comment: @user2374435: it's deprecated, but I don't think they'll drop it.